# how to play sound on multiple speaker using c++ under windows?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, media

I have a standard speaker and a bluetooth speaker. I want to play a simple wav file on both speakers simultaneously under window xp or windows 7. Is any way I can do it using c++? Thanks.

Comment: If you can set up your windows to play simultaneously on both speakers using a standard sound program (let's say - WindowsMediaPlayer), then you can easy call `PlaySound` function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx. In other way you should open each device consequentially by `waveOutOpen` function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd743866(v=vs.85).aspx register 2 callbacks and give a block of your sound data to each callback

Answer (score 0):

Also there are libraries out there to make it possible playing multiple sounds in a time.
irrKlang is one of them.

- http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/

It has very good samples if you want to start.